# Interpreting multiple line plot

Tags: data-visualization, interpretation

I am writing a thesis about predicting different series in the FRED-MD database. Before estimating the proposed model, I make the following line plot in R , it presents how the variables in the first group vary over time after making proper transformations. I wonder if this would be a good idea to make such visualisation and how can I interpret from such a line graph.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this zoomed out level, it is impossible to discern the individual lines, and it mostly looks like a mess. I recommend showing a zoomed-in plot in x, where the reader can understand what you're trying to convey. Another trick is showing the different lines at various y-offsets, like 5,10,15,... And explain this in the caption.

Comment: Thanks, would a correlation plot instead provide better insight as the data contains many variables?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a correlation plot, but it really depends on what you want to communicate to the reader. Different types of plots are useful for different purposes.